# Install latest hugo package version on Alpine

Tags: docker, alpine-linux, dockerfile, apk

I want to install the latest version of the Hugo package with apk in Alpine.
based on [pkg detail](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/community/x86_64/hugo), the latest version is `0.114.1-r0`

but when I put to run this code in Dockerfile, this has error:

```
ENV HUGO_VERSION 0.114
RUN apk add --no-cache hugo=~${HUGO_VERSION}
```

and says:

```
0.101 fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.18/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
0.240 fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.18/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
0.530 ERROR: unable to select packages:
0.532   hugo-0.111.3-r2:
0.532     breaks: world[hugo~0.114]
```

1. Why is this happening?
2. How to install the latest version with the 'pkg=version' format? I want to install the latest version by default, but I want the version to be changeable by the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest version currently available in the main repositories is `0.111` as it can be seen in the [link](https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.18/community/x86_64/) from your error message, after you <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> `hugo`. `0.114` can be only used with [edge repositories](https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community/x86_64/) as of now.

Since [these repositories](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Edge) are **not** meant to be used in production, it's recommended to just wait for the package to be updated on the `v3.18` repositories.

But if you really need to use that version for some reason, you can try this command:

```
RUN apk add --repository=https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community --no-cache hugo=~${HUGO_VERSION}
```

to install only this package from the `edge` repository.

You can also edit `/etc/apk/repositories` file as instructed [here](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Upgrading_Alpine#Upgrading_to_latest_release). The link mentioned above specifies that you have to **replace** the main repositories with the edge ones, else the system may break. The specific link you're looking to add is: https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community and also the [main](https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main) correlated repository.

Or you could try directly using `edge` [version](https://hub.docker.com/_/alpine/) in your Dockerfile.

Comment: thank's can use @edge ?

Comment: Not sure what exactly you're asking about.

Comment: my problem is solved, thank you